# set chip data initially from database in materialize css

Tags: jquery, materialize

i have string in my database separated by "," like this

```
"a","b","c","s"
```

so i want to append this string value one by one in materialize css

```
<div class="chips chips-initial"></div>
```

in this div tag

like this

```
$('.chips-initial').material_chip({
data: [{
  tag: 'Apple',
}, {
  tag: 'Microsoft',
}, {
  tag: 'Google',
}], });
```

but i am not able manage that string data like this as Json object data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have found solution for above question. This may help others to make use of Materialize CSS chips data from database/JSON.

We need to write own string to array object function to use the data in Materialize CSS chips

```
var UserPreferenceZoneData = [];

function GetUserPreference(stringdata)
{
    var userstate = stringdata; 
    var userstatearray = userstate.split(",");
    //JSON Lookup data for your string
    var ZoneJSONDataUse = {zonelist: { zone_id: a, zone_name: 'Apple'}, { zone_id: b, zone_name: 'Ball'}, }
    $.each(userstatearray, function(i, userstate) {
      $.each(ZoneJSONDataUse.zonelist, function(index, zone) {
        if(userstatearray[i]==zone.zone_id)
        {
          var obj = { id: zone.zone_id, tag: zone.zone_name };
          UserPreferenceZoneData.push(obj);
        }
      });
    });
}

//Call User Preference
var stringdata = "a,b,c,s"; // Pass your string data from database/JSON here
GetUserPreference(stringdata);

//Now chips tag generated on your chip element
  $('.chips-initial').material_chip({
    data: UserPreferenceZoneData,
   });
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i found solution :)